# C++ vector storing generic T type classes

Tags: c++, templates, generics, vector

I have a `Foo` class that expects `T` type values. I'd also like to store them in a vector. I've tried several methodologies, but didn't find any solutions. Please have a look at the source code below to get the idea what I'd like to achieve.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<class T> class Foo
{
    public:
        T getVar(T var)
        {
            return var;
        }
};

int main()
{
    template<class T>
    std::vector<Foo<T>> foos;

    Foo<int> foo1;
    Foo<double> foo2;

    foos.push_back(foo1); // doesn't work this way
    foos.push_back(foo2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Foo<int>` and `Foo<double>` are two *different* types. Vectors, like arrays, can only store elements of a single type. If you have a C++17 capable compiler look into [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) or [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant), or their Boost equivalents.

Comment: What do you want to do with the vector elements once you retrieve them? Can you show some conceptual code?

Comment: The concept is a layered architecture where each layer can have its `T` type state. I intend to use those states to communicate to an upper (abstract) layer via network/...

Comment: One solution is to have a struct Holder that contains a void pointer and an enum value that represents the type. Then store pointers to each value in the holder structure and store that in the vector. IE (bad version of std::variant): https://ideone.com/hoyPzy My implementation is unsafe as it always casts (static_cast) to whatever type you supply. std::variant most likely uses a dynamic_cast in order to throw an exception when a bad cast or bad access happens (IE: cast fails).

Comment: Also `template<class T> std::vector<Foo<T>> foos` isn't legal. You can only declare variable templates at namespace and (static) class scope.

Comment: "I intend to use those states to communicate to an upper (abstract) layer via network " --- nice description but what about code samples? `foos[i].what?`

Comment: @n.m. As for now, I only have sketches and drawings. The only code snippet I have is the one in the post.

Comment: So you know you want to put a value to a container, but you don't know exactly how you would use a value you get from a container. Perhaps it's too early to decide what types to ascribe to values and the container then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned `Foo<int>` and `Foo<double>` are different types. Meanwhile `template<typename T>Foo` or `template<class T>std::vector<Foo<T>>` are not types at all. They can be considered as layouts for types.

If you really need to store completely different types in one container use type erasure approach. For instance container `std::any` from C++17 STL. Have a look at [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4968e7500a0244a4).